# The method 'CachedNetworkImageProvider.load' has fewer positional arguments than those of overridden method 'ImageProvider.load'

Tags: android-studio, flutter, flutter-dependencies

[image]

Please help me to resolve this error in flutter, i can't understand whats the error and how to resolve it. please tell me solution briefly means where to add code lines and changes which file, thank you in advance

Comment: Please read why you [should not post screenshots of code or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).

Answer (score 9):

```
Flutter 1.12.13+hotfix.5 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 27321ebbad (12 days ago) • 2019-12-10 18:15:01 -0800
Engine • revision 2994f7e1e6
Tools • Dart 2.7.0
```

I updated the Flutter to latest today and got this error and read the [repo readme](https://github.com/renefloor/flutter_cached_network_image) and act on it. Everything works fine now thanks to package owner [Rene Floor](https://github.com/renefloor)

Just increment the package in `pubspec.yaml` as suggested by the owner:

**`cached_network_image: ^2.0.0-rc`**

By package owner:

> Breaking change with ImageProvider.load in Flutter 1.10
>
> The Flutter team made a breaking change with the ImageProvider in Flutter 1.10.15 (currently Master channel only).
>
> If you are experiencing one of the following errors upgrade to 2.0.0-rc.
>
> The method 'ScaledFileImage.load' has fewer positional arguments than those of overridden method 'ImageProvider.load'
>
> The method 'CachedNetworkImageProvider.load' has fewer positional arguments than those of overridden method

Answer (score 2):

according to package documentation on [here](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image)

> The Flutter team made a breaking change with the ImageProvider in Flutter 1.10.15 (currently Master channel only).
>
> If you are experiencing one of the following errors upgrade to 2.0.0-rc.